# Build QR code and display image without saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, qr-code

I want to build QR Code of a particular string/url. After building, without saving I want to display the display the image. I don't want to persist the image. Something like `http://example.com/qrcode?code=LOL`,
should display the QR code for the string LOL.

Platform : Ruby on Rails 4

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do the process somewhere other than your server.

I'd suggest either using an out of the box API like: http://goqr.me/api/

Or even do it on the browser (if it's a web app) like: https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs

Disclaimer: I have not used any of these.

All the best :)